# Why can higher order functions be declared without specifying that they need an input?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

For if I wanted to make a higher order function that filters even numbers out of a list using the predefined filter function I can do it like this:

```
filtereven list = filter even list
```

but another thing that still works is:

```
filtereven = filter even
```

why does this work and how does it know that it should expect an input list?

Comment: The word you're looking for is `currying`. Unlike most other programming languages, Haskell functions are "curried" by default, which makes usages like this possible (and natural).

Comment: How does it know?  Types!

Comment: (Specifically, the type of `filter`. `filter` is declared with (curried) type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, which is the same as `(a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a])` (function type arrow `->` is right associative, so you can always add parentheses on its right side). Therefore `filter anyPredicate` must have type `[a] -> [a]`, which is a thing that expects an input list.)

Comment: You do this in English too.  You can say "To teach is to understand" (`teach = understand`) without having to say "To teach something is to understand that thing" (`teach x = understand x`)"